# Obtener posicion de sum(campo) ordenado de mayor a menor

Tags: mysql

Buenos dias, tengo una consulta que hace un sum de un puntaje segun usuario y luego los ordena de mayor a menor:

```
select distinct usuario as u, (select sum(puntajeProde) from prodeApuesta 
where usuario = u) as total
from prodeApuesta order by total desc
```

Como puedo hacer para agregar un id autoincrementable a la consulta para poder obtener la posicion donde quedo el usuario, ej:

Juan 30
Leo 20
Maria 10

La posicion de Leo es la 2

Comment: Independiente de cómo lograr ese correlativo....esta definitivamente no es la forma en la que deberías hacer ese `sum`

Comment: No estarías respondiendo a la pregunta ni aportando algo que me ayude a mejorar, por lo que no entiendo la razon de tu comentario

Comment: No estoy respondiendo la pregunta porque ésta es de cómo lograr un autoincrementador en mysql, y no tengo cómo testearlo. Sobre mi otro comentario, bueno, lo hice como aviso para que revises tu consulta. No veo el motivo para ponerse a la defensiva cuando alguien te comenta que lo que estás haciendo no es lo correcto

Comment: Sería ideal si pudieras añadir el esquema de las tablas relacionadas con la pregunta (solo los campos usados e id's sería suficiente), para que podamos ver mejor qué es lo que haces y si hay alguna manera mejor de hacerlo (esto parece un caso en el que usar joins/group by sería de utilidad).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No es necesario un join, es la misma tabla. Simplemente debería ser `SELECT usuario, sum(puntajeProde)  FROM prodeApuesta GROUP BY usuario`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declarando una variable

```
SET @rank=0;
select @rank:=@rank+1, distinct usuario as u, (select sum(puntajeProde) from prodeApuesta 
  where usuario = u) as total
  from prodeApuesta order by total desc
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Era lo que necesitaba!